# Error: class X is public, should be declared in file named X

Tags: java, class, display

I am searching for a Java compiler that I can use online that includes a graphic output and can support swing, I'm new to this however and I am unsure of what the problem is, I've searched up a simple draw circle program, and I use it to test whether the compiler has a graphic output and supports swing or not, currently, I've stumbled across a website that seems to support graphic outputs but I get an error saying that the class is public and should be in a file, any help or suggestions for compilers?

The website is https://www.codechef.com/ide#  Any downloaded compilers are too complex for a beginner like me to navigate around :/

My code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class DrawCircle extends Frame //this is the place of error
{

    Shape circle=new Ellipse2D.Float(100.0f,100.0f,100.0f,100.0f);


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D ga=(Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(circle);
        ga.setPaint(Color.blue);
        ga.fill(circle);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame frame=new DrawCircle();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(300, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Java expects a public class to exist in a file of the same name. Obviously, you can't see the filesystem since this is a website, but it will not be called `DrawCircle`. (they could do some magic to put a public class into a file with the corresponding name, but evidently they don't)

Comment: *any help or suggestions for compilers?* Download the JDK and use a real IDE. It's really not that hard to do (and if you want an easy one, I would recommend [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) - I personally use eclipse and vscode a lot, a lot of people like intellij). Online IDEs are mostly toys; they're great for very small proof of concept type things but not writing standalone GUI applications.

Comment: As the site says when you first choose Java as the language: "*Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public*". So either remove the `public` keyword, or change the name of the class to `Main`.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone!